# Undefined Offset when trying to loop through array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to convert my array:

```
$tdata = array(11,3,8,12,5,1,9,13,5,7);
```

Into a string like this:

```
11-3-8-12-5-1-9-13-5-7
```

I was able to get it work with:

```
$i = 0;
$predata = $tdata[0];
foreach ($tdata as $value)
{
    $i++;
    if ($i == 10) {break;}
    $predata.='-'.$tdata[$i];

}
```

But was wondering if there is an easier way?

I tried something like:

```
$predata = $tdata[0];

foreach ($tdata as $value)
{
    if($value !== 0) {
        $predata.= '-'.$tdata[$value];
    }
}
```

but it result in bunch of `Undefined Offset` errors and incorrect `$predata` at the end.

So I want to learn once and for all:

1. How to loop through the entire array starting from index 1 (while excluding index 0)?
2. Is there a better approach to convert array into string in the fashion described above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is a better approach to this task. Use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$tdata = array(11,3,8,12,5,1,9,13,5,7);
echo implode('-', $tdata); // this glues all the elements with that particular string.
```

To answer question #1, You could use a loop and do this:

```
$tdata = array(11,3,8,12,5,1,9,13,5,7);
$out = '';
foreach ($tdata as $index => $value) { // $value is a copy of each element inside `$tdata`
// $index is that "key" paired to the value on that element
    if($index != 0) { // if index is zero, skip it
        $out .= $value . '-';
    }
}
// This will result into an extra hypen, you could right trim it

echo rtrim($out, '-');
```

Comment: What???? So simple???? I was going crazy with those loops when there was a one string solution all along... THANK YOU!

Comment: @Acidon yes there is a built in function in PHP that already does this :) . Glad i was able to help

Comment: ahh, thanks for the answer for 1st question as well, you are the man! Using `trim` is brilliant and would work for my case as well :) God, I love PHP!